# regex for match inside a word

Tags: regex

Say I have following similar texts:

```
_startOneEnd
_startTwoEnd
_startThreeEnd
```

I want to match on:
begins with **_start**
ends with **End**
and I want capture the bit in-between, e.g., One, Two, Three in the variable above:

Can anyone suggest a regex to capture this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If each line of input contains only the text similar to your examples, something like this should work:

```
/^_start(.*)End$/
```

The `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the string. The `$` anchors it to the end of the string. The parenthesis capture the middle part.

Comment: Only if you turn on multiline mode for this regex. Then it's correct.

Comment: @JanDvorak It doesn't look like the pattern he's trying to match spans lines. I'm assuming the input is processed line by line.

Comment: You're right. These look like separate strings. The description is still sligtly off ("of the line" => "of the string")

Comment: @JanDvorak Ok, I modified it as per your suggestion.

Comment: A word of warning on this one, reading between the lines as it isn't outlined in the question. This will match on `_startOne End` so if you don't want to match whitespace in the middle section change the `.` to something more appropriate, possibly `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

In `C#`, you may use this:

```
(?<=_start).*(?=End)
```

Comment: Javascript does not support lookbehind. Any other regex engine I know can do this.

Comment: Not everything revolves around JavaScript. Is it mentioned somewhere in the question?

Comment: Do I sound like everything did revolve around Javascript? I just mentioned JS as the outsider here, as it _could_ be for Javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment :)

Comment: The lookbehind/ahead seem overkill in this scenario, there is no real need for them.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear if the part in the middle may only be the examples given.
If so, use this:

```
_start((One)|(Two)|(Three))End
```

If not, is it can be anything, try this:

```
_start(.*?)End
```

Note that the match is non-greedy.